# $|.|$ and $d'$ are not equivalent (in metric sense)?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Please i need a counter example why $|.|$ and $d'$ are not metricly equivalent where: 
$$d'(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
  0, & x=y, \\
  |x|+|y|, & x\neq y.
\end{array}\right.$$

Thank you very much .

Comment: Is $\mid . \mid$ a norm on a $\mathbb R$ vector space?

Comment: @Stefan $|.|$ is the natural distance on $\mathbb{R}$ if $d=|.|$ then $d(x,y)=|x-y|$

Comment: How do the $\epsilon$ neighborhoods of $1$ w.r.t. $d'$ look like?

Comment: @user251257 what ?

Comment: If both metrics are equivalent then the neighborhoods w.r.t. one metric contains the neighborhoods of the other metric and vice versa.

Comment: @user251257 this is topological equivalence

Comment: @Vrouvrou metrical equivalence implies topological equivalence

Comment: And no. Your metrics are not topologically equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: This can also help, since metric equivalence implies topological equivalence:
Given any $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, let $\varepsilon =\frac{|x|}{2}$, then  the epsilon ball $B_{d'}(x,\varepsilon)$ consists only of $\{x\}$. For, if $y\not= x$ and $y \in B_{d'}(x,\varepsilon)$, we must have $\varepsilon < |x|+|y| < \varepsilon$, a contradiction. For $x=0$, $B_{d'}(0,\varepsilon) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\ |\ |x|< \varepsilon\} = (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ . Thus, $0$ is the only point that is not open in $(X,d')$.

Comment: Can we find a counter example without using topological equivalence ?

Comment: I proved that it is not topologicaly equivalent but i don't know how to find un counter example without using topological equivalence

Comment: If $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent, then for each $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ there are constants $c$ and $c'$ such that $cd(x,y)\leq d'(x,y) \leq c'd(x,y)$. Assume such constants exist and obtain a contradiction.

Comment: we have alwayse that  $d(x,y)\leq d'(x,y)$ if i suppose that there exists $c'$ such that $d'(x,y)\leq c' d(x,y)$ i.e $|x|+|y|\leq c' |x-y|$

Answer (score 0):

If $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent, then for each $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ there are constants $c$ and $c'$ such that $cd(x,y)\leq d'(x,y) \leq c'd(x,y)$. For any $x\not=y \in \mathbb{R} \ :\ d(x,y) = |x-y| \leq |x|+|y| = d(x,y)$, we need only show that no $c'$ can exist. Assume the contrary. Choose an integer $N' > c'$. Then, $d'(N',N'+1)=2N'+1 > c' = c'd(N',N'+1).$ Therefore, $c'$ can't exist.